# What is intuition behind constant false alarm detection?

Tags: probability, statistics, signal-processing

We use CFAR detection when noise variance is not known which means estimate depend upon noise variance. As the decision threshold has to satisfy probability of false, we assume that testing is under $H_0$ rather than $H_1$, this makes our estimate biased. This in turn decreases detection probability $P_D$.  Most text books use the idea of employing reference noise $\eta_R$ samples to avoid the dependability of ML(maximum likelihood) estimate on noise variance.

Can someone please explain what is the role of reference noise samples and how they are able to enhance the $P_D$?

Comment: What hypothesis is being tested and what is the alternative? What is the test statistic? Please define $P_D$ and $\eta_R.$ Why would one want to "avoid the dependability of MLE" of noise variance.?

Comment: I am considering a simple hypothesis problem  i.e $x = w: H_0 (null)$ and $x =s+w: H_1(alternative)$, noise $w \sim \mathcal{N}[0, \sigma^2 I]$. Now probability of detection $P_D$ is  a concepts of counting the the number of signals that survive a specific threshold under alternative hypothesis.  Now why is this required to avoid dependency of MLE on noise variance, I guess this is way of making $P_{fa}$ constant and avoid bias in signal.  Because $E[\hat{\sigma}^2] = \sigma^2 + signal$, that is a biased signal.  Therefore, it is suggested to  employ the reference noise samples.